# Using powershell to download an embedded video

Tags: regex, powershell, video

I need to download a monthly broadcast automatically (will set a scheduled task) using powershell.

Here is the embedded URL: https://www.jw.org/download/?fileformat=MP4&output=html&pub=jwb&issue=201601&option=TRGCHlZRQVNYVrXF&txtCMSLang=E

The only thing that changes each month is the 201602, 201603, etc. Once I have able to pull the 720p video file, I will work on programmatically adding that part of the URL, based on the current system clock (I can manage this)

I have tried these without success:

**Attempt 1:**

```
$source = "https://www.jw.org/download/?fileformat=MP4&output=html&pub=jwb&issue=201601&option=TRGCHlZRQVNYVrXF&txtCMSLang=E"
$destination = "c:\broadcasts\test.mp4"
Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$source = "https://www.jw.org/download/?fileformat=MP4&output=html&pub=jwb&issue=201601&option=TRGCHlZRQVNYVrXF&txtCMSLang=E"
$dest = "c:\broadcasts\test.mp4"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
$url = "https://www.jw.org/download/?fileformat=MP4&output=html&pub=jwb&issue=201601&option=TRGCHlZRQVNYVrXF&txtCMSLang=E"
$output = "c:\broadcasts\test.mp4"
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
```

Both of these end up with a test.mp4 that is basically just an empty file.

Then I found the another page that holds the video (and the download links for different qualities) and tried to pull these links using the following (I know I could have used $webpage.links):

**Attempt 4:**

```
$webpage=Invoke-webrequest "http://tv.jw.org/#en/video/VODStudio/pub-
jwb_201601_1_VIDEO"
$webpage.RawContent | Out-File "c:\scripts\webpage.txt" ASCII -Width 9999
```

And found that the raw content doesn't have the mp4 visible. My idea was to pull the raw content, parse it with regex and grab the 720p URL, save it in a variable and then send that to a BitsTransfer bit of code.

Please help?

Comment: Getting an empty file sounds like the web server is streaming the video, not offering it as an ordinary download. This requires some extra support from downloading application. What's more, the site is using a CDN, which may cause extra troubles.Taking into account the domain, I'd guess you could contact the organization and ask if they provide stand-alone downloads for, say, using videos in places without reliable internet connection.

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks, that does make sense. However, on that second link referenced in "attempt 4", there is a download button and the dropdown allows you to select "720", which gives you this download link (https://download-a.akamaihd.net/files/media_broadcasting/e8/jwb_E_201601_01_r720P.mp4) so there are standalone downloads, I just want to grab them automatically :). Also note that with each download, there is a two character wildcard (in this case, /e8/) that makes using this URL as the base for future downloads (almost?) impossible, unless I am mistaken.